# How to Navigate A Grid

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Let's say I have the following grid:

[image: Grid Outline 0,0 .. 3,5]

I can't seem to figure out how to navigate it using a for loop starting in the bottom left hand corner. The order of cells should be

```
0,5 => 0,4 => 1,5 => 1,4 => 0,3 => 2,5, => 1,3 => 2,4 => 2,3...
```

Another way to visualize it:

```
(1) 0,5 => 
(2) 0,4 => (1,5) (1,4)
(3) 0,3 => (2,5) (1,3) (2,4) (2,3)
(4) 0,2 => (3,5) (1,2) (3,4) (2,2) (3,3) (3,2)
```

So Here is the Pattern that I see:

1. To start each loop take the previous loops value (x,y) and make it (x, y-1)
2. So then the pattern emerges that goes like: (+1, y) (x,-1) (+1, y) (x, -1) and so you could pull the old values and alternate increasing x with decreasing y.

Is a for loop the wrong tool for this job?

Is there a clever algorithm that will do so I don't have to pull the previous value and can just calculate them? Am I barking up the wrong tree here and should I approach it differently (correctly?)?

**EDIT:**

Here is an attempt at drawing the Path. Not sure if this makes more sense:

[image]

The idea is start in the bottom left corner on the first cell. Go up one cell, and then alternate as they form a right angle. Once the complete right angle is formed, go up one cell and alternate to form a new right angle.

Comment: I don't get the kind of path you're after (despite your examples). Could you perhaps draw the path in the grid?

Comment: After you get to (3,2) how does the path go? Or is the grid continuing in x and y? Is it infinite?

Comment: @Helen the grid isn't infinite. You can assume there are less than 20 columns and rows. However, they might not be square.

Comment: So after (3,2) does it go (0,1) -> (1,1) -> (2,1) -> (3,1) -> (0,0) ... ?

Comment: This looks somewhat like a Z-order (or Morton) curve; the wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) points at an algorithm which may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution, edited for non square grid:

```
for(startY = maxY, startY >= 0; startY++)
{
    x1 = 0;
    y1 = startY;
    x2 = 5 - startY;
    y2 = 5;

    while(!(x1 == x2 && y1 == y2))
    {
        if(x1 <= maxX)
            //Point 1 is x1, y1

        if(y2 >= 0)
            //Point 2 is x2, y2

        x1++;
        y2--;
    }

    if(x1 <= maxX)
        //Final point is x1, y1
}
```

So you calculate two points on each iteration of the while loop and the last diagonal point for each iteration through the for loop after the rest of the points for that section of the path.